# В чем разница между краткой и полной записью выражения if-else?

Tags: python

Не могу понять почему интерпретатор выдает ошибку при краткой записи if-else, а в полной нет? Подскажите в чем ошибка написания краткой записи?

```
rate = 5

if rate == 5: 
  rate += 2 
else: 
  rate += 0
print(rate)

rate += 2 if rate == 5 else rate += 0 
print(rate)
```

Comment: `rate += 2 * (rate == 5)`

Comment: rate = rate + 2 if rate == 5 else rate + 0

Answer (score 1):

Правильно так:

```
rate += 2 if rate == 5 else 0
```

Смысл короткой формы - вернуть один из двух результатов в зависимости от условия:

```
<результат_если_истина> if <проверка_на_истину> else <результат_если_ложь>
```

Две формы `if` не взаимозаменяемы, они всё же разные.

Comment: А если необходимо действие, если условие на истину не выполнено, то краткая запись не подходит?

Comment: @PetePetePete, подходит, например `print('a') if True else print('b')`

Comment: @Zhihar Ну это только потому, что в третьем питоне `print` - это функция. Конечно, функции вызывать можно. Но вот с операторами уже не получится ничего.

Comment: @CrazyElf, например что бы хотелось сделать с операторами, что не возможно тернарным оператором - просто никогда не сталкивался и хотелось бы пощупать

Comment: Если к примеру такое выражение 
rate += 2 if rate == 5 else <вычитание 3>, то как это правильно записать?

Comment: @PetePetePete `rate = rate + 2 if rate == 5 else rate - 3` так не подходит?

Comment: Нет, так нельзя. Смысл в том, что <результат_если_ложь> или <результат_если_истина> должны быть константами, а не выражениями. Вообще, в понимании того, как это устроено в Питоне, сильно помогает занение тернарного оператора в других языках: что то = <условие> <значение, если условие истинно> : <значение, если условие ложно>